# How do I communicate to my boss that I am unwilling to perform a task because it may be illegal?

Tags: professionalism, management, work-environment, manager, job-satisfaction

My boss has instructed a co-worker to edit some papers with Photoshop to add information that is not true (and maybe use it later on court).

He is concerned that making these edits would cause him some legal trouble.
I'll have to check with lawyers to see if he could have any consequences from knowingly taking part in this falsification.

If my friend just isn't comfortable with this task, or finds out it truly would be illegal to do so, how can my friend address this issue with his boss in such a way that conveys he has real concerns rather than just trying to avoid having to do the work?

Comment: You might want to ask an actual lawyer about this.

Comment: Is this not off topic?

Comment: @Marriott81 I'm not asking whether is legal or not, but rather how to handle that with the boss. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: It actually is a legal question. Technically, they should be perfectly capable to reject that request, given they are able to communicate. *Can* they reject a direct request, though? That has only legal implications. Consequences if they were found out would also be purely legal.

Comment: @CMW consequences of rejecting the task is not purely legal, as the way you handle it will make the difference between a nice job environment and a bad one (implying he doesn't get fired for rejecting it).

Comment: @Worker That on the other hand, solely depends on your working environment and the personality of your boss. I've worked with bosses who I could call names and tell them they're full of it, and the work environment would still be fine, and with other where the slightest hint of disobedience would cause major trouble. This is obviously something we can't know about your company.

Comment: @CMW thanks anyway, while you are right and each boss can be different, the answers given for this question were really useful and my friend will use them to approach the boss.

Comment: I'm happy the answers help you and your friend. Glad the community could help.

Comment: @Worker - Questions here do better if they have a goal in mind already.  We can not really tell you what your goal should be, but we can help you achieve that goal.  I have made an edit to the question which is what I am thinking your goal basically is. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Chad & PsychoData thanks for the edit. I think it shows better what I was trying to say :)

Comment: This question is not off-topic.  Asking advice on how to approach a boss because there is an issue that may not be legal is *not the same as* asking for legal advice on the legality of the issue.  Talking to your boss is not, in and of itself, a legal issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Warning: I'm not a lawyer

The fact that your boss asked a co-worker, instead of doing it himself, shows his real motives. The person who fudges the documents is the one who gets the blame (and possible prosecution). If you look at these big banks and their scandals, you often hear about how "shocked" the senior managers were that fraud was happening right beneath them. They can claim that because there are no official records that put any blame on them. Some low level trader gets all the blame and is fired.

This is a dangerous issue with no real solution. Your friend should ask his boss to confirm what he wants to do in writing. If the boss refuses, your friend should send an email anyway, saying something like:

> Dear boss, can you confirm by email that you want me to photoshop and modify contract XX? PS- Can you also confirm this is legal?

CC HR and anyone else involved.

He should then print the email and keep a copy, as it might be used in a court. Remember, the boss will deny everything. Always assume that the thing will end up in court, and everyone connected to the case will be treated with suspicion. So keep all records, don't agree to anything, even verbally, and be sure to update your resume in case it gets ugly.

Comment: He already have an e-mail from the boss with this request. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: @Worker Depends on what the email says. Ask your colleague to reply with something like "Dear boss, I am worried this might be illegal. Can you please get the company legal advisor to confirm this is ok?" If the company doesn't have a legal advisor, ask the company to hire one, as it's their business

Comment: How can a printed e-mail be used in court? Anyone can write a text document and print it.

Comment: @vsz: usually opposing counsel submits a request for all email records as part of the process.  The company would have to produce the emails that are in their system.  So, it's not just what one person prints.  It's what the email server gives up.  Bearing in mind that it's possible to determine that things have been deleted..

Comment: If you are not a lawyer then you should not be giving this advice, even with the IANAL disclaimer.

Comment: @vsz ahhh, but nowadays most email is html! and everyone knows that no-one can write HTM-oh wait...but yeah it's asking for the emails from the company not taking their word at a printed copy.

Comment: @Worker HR, in my experience, usually is the most familiar with laws regarding workers. She might have some guidance for you about whether or not it would be legal, but that is not a substitute for actual lawyer-(al?) advice

Comment: @PsychoData there is no HR in this company.. it's very small (10-15 people) and I think I forgot to mention that the boss is also the company owner.

Comment: @Worker, the tale is getting messier by the minute. I suggest you seek professional advice